# image scaling in android device

Tags: android, html, css

i m using css3 to scale an image when image is clicked by the user i m assigning this css to an image it runs perfectly on browser but when i run it on the android it don't scale the image only translate method is working

```
.scaleImage{
-moz-animation-name: AN-ani-17;
-webkit-animation-name: AN-ani-17;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes AN-ani-17 {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}


50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 380px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1.5, 1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}

/*  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 270px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1.2, 1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}*/

100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 470px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1.6, 1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes AN-ani-17 {
0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
}


50% {
    -moz-transform:translate(0px, 380px, 0px) scale(1, 1.5, 1);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
}


100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 470px, 0px) scale(1, 1.6, 1);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

}

how to run it on android device

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Android 2.2 or later? CSS3 scaling's not functioning on Android is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12451). Star it if you'd like to see it fixed.

Related: [CSS3 animation flicker on Android 2.2 (webkit-transform:translate(..) scale(..) at the same time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270208/css3-animation-flicker-on-android-2-2-webkit-transformtranslate-scale)